# iOS Background App Fetch not working

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, background-fetch

So, I want go check something using a API with location and send a `UILocalNotification`.
This is how I get the locations in AppDelegate from another class:

```
locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    if gotResponse {
        return
    }
    locationA = locations
    gotResponse = !gotResponse
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    let locationArray = locationA as NSArray
    let locationObj = locationArray.lastObject as! CLLocation
    let coord = locationObj.coordinate
    let latitude = coord.latitude
    let longitude = coord.longitude
    lat = latitude
    long = longitude
    AppDelegate.lat = latitude
    AppDelegate.long = longitude
```

And in AppDelegate I have this:

```
@UIApplicationMain
```

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

```
static var lat = CLLocationDegrees()
static var long = CLLocationDegrees()
```

`....`

```
func application(application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {


    let currentURL = "\(AppDelegate.lat),\(AppDelegate.long)?"
    print("currentURLInBackround: \(currentURL)    \(application.scheduledLocalNotifications!.count)")

    Answers.logCustomEventWithName("Sent RainAlerts", customAttributes: nil)

    Alamofire.request(.GET, currentURL)
        .responseJSON { response in
            let jsonData: AnyObject?
            do {
                jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(response.data!, options: [])
                guard let jsonDict = jsonData as? NSDictionary else {return}
                guard let dailyDict = jsonDict["daily"] as? NSDictionary else {return}
                guard let dataArr = dailyDict["data"] as? NSArray else {return}
                guard let tomorrowTemp = dataArr[1] as? NSDictionary else {return}
                guard let precipChance = tomorrowTemp["precipProbability"] as? Double else {return}
                print("There is a chance of rain of: \(Int(precipChance * 100) )")

                // MARK: set push notification
                if self.defaults.boolForKey("rainAlertSwitch") == true && Int(precipChance * 100) > 40 && application.scheduledLocalNotifications?.count == 0{

                    let notifTime: NSDate = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(1.0)
                    let notification: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
                  // Configure notification    
                application.scheduledLocalNotifications?.append(notification)
                    Answers.logCustomEventWithName("Sent RainAlerts", customAttributes: nil)

                }



            }catch{

            }




        }
    completionHandler (.NewData)



}
```

My problem is that my analytics keep saying that the app crashes on `performFetchWithCompletionHandler`. I do Debug->Stimulate Background Fetch on a actual device and works just fine. I don't know why analytics says the app crashes on users.

Here is the analytics link to the crash: http://crashes.to/s/86193953c05

Comment: Your network request is going to complete asynchronously, but you are calling the completionHandler outside the closure, before the network request completes. I am not sure if it's the cause of your crash, but you should move the completionHandler call into your closure.

Comment: Did that. Still crashing.

Answer (score 0):

`response.data` is nil.

However, you do not call `completionHandler`